# How do I import data into my SAS Session, so that I can start analysing it?

Tags: import, sas

I have some data called "abc_partner_data" within a permanent library called "Input_SAS", within SAS. I want to import the data into my SAS session so that I can start analysing the data. The code I have used to do this is below:

```
data abc_partner_data;
set Input_SAS.abc_partner_data*;
run;
```

However I keep getting two errors. Firstly SAS states "Libref abc_partner_data exceeds 8 characters". So can I change the  Libref name to any name I want?

Also SAS states "the File WORK.SDP_POLICY_CUST_DATA does not exist". I am not sure how to solve this problem. Any suggestions would be useful!

Comment: to start with, what format is your data in?

Comment: @DCR It was originally an Excel CSV

Comment: You cannot have a permanent SAS library named `Input_SAS` as the maximum length for a libref is 8 characters.

Answer (score 1):

1. open sas click on library icon
2. right click in the explorer window and create a library, specify enable at start up
3. left click your new library
4. left click 'file' on the toolbar in sas
5. click on import data

Comment: I have called the library "analytic" and I get the error Libref ANALYTIC is not assigned. Check the SAS log for possible additional information. Do you know why?

Comment: @jed Either the code is incorrect or the path is incorrect. If you're working from SAS on a server, your local computer may not be a valid path as well.

Comment: yes, when you create the library you need to specify the folder path - where on your disk you want to keep your sas files.  so, delete the library and then recreate it like you did before but specify c:\somefolder as your path.  Make sure the folder already exists on your hard drive

Comment: if you are running sas from a server ask someone else who is using sas how to specify the path for files on the server

Comment: @DCR Okay thanks, it works now! One last question, do the column headings within my SAS dataset have to be of a certain number of characters or certain format for SAS to recognise the column headings?

Comment: variable names can be up to 32 characters in length.  When you import there's an option to specify that the first row contains column names.  If this works accept the answer so others know the problem has been solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the libname statement which defines the library `Input_SAS` and change it to 8 characters name. for example `InputSAS`

Then edit the code to be like:

```
libname InputSAS '<libname_path>';
data abc_partner_data;
set InputSAS.abc_partner_data*;
run;
```

Note: the libname statement assumes it is a SAS Base library please check the [libname documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#chloptfmain.htm)

The dataset `work.abc_partner_data` will be existed after this code finishes successfully